# Silent APN Notification not working for Firebase IOS Auth

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm currently trying to implementation Auth for iOS using Firebase. I've gotten it to work using the recaptcha method specified here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth but still running into issues with the silent APN. I uploaded my APN key to the firebase project and added push notification to my swift project capabilities. I also added the following piece of code to my AppNameApp.swift file:

```
class Appdelegate : NSObject,UIApplicationDelegate{
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
    }
 
}
```

I'm still unable to get it to work and I've been stuck for a few days now. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the thing that you so-call Silent APN Notification?  Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Comment: Under the link I sent, Firebase has another option outside of cloud messaging called Silent APNS:

Comment: Enable app verification

To use phone number authentication, Firebase must be able to verify that phone number sign-in requests are coming from your app. There are two ways Firebase Authentication accomplishes this:

Silent APNs notifications: When you sign in a user with their phone number for the first time on a device, Firebase Authentication sends a token to the device using a silent push notification. If your app successfully receives the notification from Firebase, phone number sign-in can proceed.
....

Comment: any luck ? did u solve the issue ? I am geting error as requests from your ios client application <empty> are blocked